# Can't add additional text to append() function with object?

Tags: arrays, each

I used the :contains selector to capture dom elements into an array variable. I'm trying to output the array, but I need to wrap the whole array collection.

```
        $.each(arrayEx, function(i, val){
           $(".target").append("<div>" + val + "</div>");
        });
```

**I'm using .each() because I might have to work with each object in the array as well.**

I can't seem to get the val to output html if I include the div text like that. I've tried html() and text(). [Object, Object] or undefined is all that gets output.

If i take out the "div" text, to have just

```
           $(".target").append(val);
```

it outputs html fine, but I really need it wrapped/modify-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `val` is a DOM element, it needs to be converted to a jQuery object before you can call `html()`, etc. on it:

```
$(".target").append("<div>" + $(val).text() + "</div>")
```

Comment: val is a collection of dom elements, will this still apply? (away from pc to test).

Comment: @Karric Not sure what you mean. A jQuery object that's created with `jQuery()` or `$()` is by definition a collection of DOM elements.